# Excel from string data to integer

Tags: c#, string, excel

I add data from a text to excel with insert into, but it's always show string format. I want it float format(0.2, 1, 20) and I cant change them in excel (for example a coloumn in one time, only it could be changed by one by for all cells). I tried tryparse or converttoint32 func. but nothing change in excel, the numbers are still in text format..

```
public void ExcelWrite(string date, string station_name, string station_no, string xvaluee) 

{

        try
        {   float j;
            xvaluee=xvaluee.Trim();
            float.TryParse(Valuee, out j);
            string szConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C://data.xls';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(szConn);

            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Sayfa1$]([Station_No],[Station_Name],[Date],[Valuee]) VALUES('" + station_no + "','" + station_name + "','" + date + "','" + j  + "')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }



     }
```

Answer (score 1):

since you adding `''` for each parameter all will take as `strings`

use Parameters as below

```
using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(szConn ))
{
    cn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Sayfa1$]([Station_No],[Station_Name],[Date],[Valuee]) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", cn);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", station_no );
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", station_name );
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",date );
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", j);
   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I also change IMEX value to 1 for mixformat. the problem is solved.